# Javascript: замена одних символов на другие с помощью регулярных выражений (одна сложная регулярка или несколько простых)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, оптимизация, поиск, замена

Приветствую

Требуется в тексте заменить одни символы на другие (вернее части текста на другие). В моем случае превратить текст к html код, заменив некоторые специальные символы.

Мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
    var htmlCode = htmlText.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                             .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
                             .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                             .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
                             .replace(/'/g, "&#039;")
                             .replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

В связи с верой в регулярные выражения у меня возникло пара вопросов:

1) можно ли как-то упростить код и сделать замену с помощью только одного регулярного выражения, который включит в себя все необходимые варианты, указанные выше

2) если 1) возможен, то что лучше использовать - одно сложное регулярное выражение или несколько простых? В целях оптимизации кода (скорости исполнения, затрачиваемых ресурсах и т.д.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787322/htmlspecialchars-equivalent-in-javascript). Функция, которая обладает лучшей производительностью и довольно легко читаема:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```

По поводу второго вопроса: я бы пожертвовал читаемостью кода, только если прирост производительности будет больше в несколько раз.